# Test column value in XSLT

Tags: excel, xslt

How can I test a column value in xsl?

I've tried:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="field[@name='SUBCAT'] = Z_TLS">
        ...
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

And also

```
<xsl:if test="field[@name='SUBCAT'] = Z_TLS">
            ...
</xsl:if>
```

Where field[@name='SUBCAT'] referees to the column "SUBCAT" in the excel file I'm mapping

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. (I am not aware of an Excel file format that has a `field` element, so I am looking forward to seeing your input example.)

Comment: If you are trying to test the value of the field against a **string**, you need to quote the string: `test="field[@name='SUBCAT'] = 'Z_TLS'"`.

Answer (score -2):

I used when instead of if:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="field[@name='SUBCAT'] = 'Z_PMS'">
        ...
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: That doesn't solve anything. And if you have only a single `xsl:when` with no `xsl:otherwise` then you *should* be using `xsl:if`.

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: Maybe, but not because of what you claim. It could be just the added quotes that made the difference.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).